# Matplotlib Date Index Formatting

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am using matplotlib to plot some financial data.  However, in its default configuration matplotlib inserts gaps in place of missing data.  The documentation recommends using a [date index formatter](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/examples/api/date_index_formatter.html) to resolve this.

However, can be seen in the examples provided on the page:

- The formatting has changed from "Sept 03 2008" => "2008-09-03"
- The chart no longer ends on the final sample, but rather is padded to "2008-10-14".

How can I retain this default behavior while still avoiding gaps in the data?

**Edit**

Sample code, from the documentation, with the desired ticks on top.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.mlab as mlab
import matplotlib.cbook as cbook
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker

datafile = cbook.get_sample_data('aapl.csv', asfileobj=False)
print 'loading', datafile
r = mlab.csv2rec(datafile)

r.sort()
r = r[-30:]  # get the last 30 days


# first we'll do it the default way, with gaps on weekends
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.plot(r.date, r.adj_close, 'o-')
fig.autofmt_xdate()

# next we'll write a custom formatter
N = len(r)
ind = np.arange(N)  # the evenly spaced plot indices

def format_date(x, pos=None):
    thisind = np.clip(int(x+0.5), 0, N-1)
    return r.date[thisind].strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.plot(ind, r.adj_close, 'o-')
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(ticker.FuncFormatter(format_date))
fig.autofmt_xdate()

plt.show()
```

Comment: Give a clear example, please. A peace of code, what it prints and what you want it to print.

Comment: @erikb85: I've attached the specific example used in the documentation.  It demonstrates the resulting differences in tick formatting.

Comment: @erikb85: The code above is runnable. If you don't have the csv, matplotlib downloads it for you.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I'll answer the easy part: To get `Sept 03 2008` instead of `2008-09-03` use `strftime('%b %d %Y')`:

```
def format_date(x, pos=None):
    thisind = np.clip(int(x+0.5), 0, N-1)
    result = r.date[thisind].strftime('%b %d %Y')
    return result
```

PS. The last date in `r.date` is `Oct 14 2008`, so I don't think it is a bad thing to include a tick mark for it. Are you sure you don't want it?

Comment: It is a little bit more complicated than this as if the data is over a much larger range (say years) Matplotlib might pick years (e.g, 2007, 2008, 2009) to be the major tick marks.  Clearly there is some magic going on behind the scenes.